# Can we create a customized URL for the file which is selected from the input type="file" which points to file and downloads the file wherever used?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <input type="file" id="ota" name="ota" accept=".bin" />
 <div id="btn-container">
 <button id="update-button" >Update</button>
 </div>
```

Here when file is selected from input type="file" i want to create a URL similar like(http://<server_host_ip>:<server_port>/<image_name.bin>)

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
document.getElementById("ota").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const file = this.files[0];
  const fileName = file.name;
  console.log(fileName)
  const link = document.getElementById("dl")
  link.href = location.origin + "/" + fileName
  link.removeAttribute("hidden")
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="ota" name="ota" accept=".bin" />
<button id="update-button">Update</button>
<a href="" download id="dl" hidden>download</a>
```

Comment: Here the link format what i need is correct but it is not downloading the file, i mean to say it is not pointing to the file which is taken from input type="file".So can u tell how to download the file using that link?

Comment: It has to upload first or you need to create a data uri. But why meisje the user download the file he just uploaded?

Comment: ya i need to create a data URI , it is actually like im sending the link to the ESP controller so that by using this link we should be able to download the file